# how to make my query read letter(Ñ)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

my query filtration wont filter names with letter(`Ñ`) in there names....can anyone help me make my query read and filter names with letter(`Ñ`) on it...please.

everytime theres an Ñ on there name my query will read it as a null.

[image]

current code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="search" id="query"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#query").autocomplete({
        source : 'search.php',
        select : function(event,ui){
            $("#query").html(ui.item.value);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

search.php code:

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['term'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("klayton");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name 
FROM tb_applicants
WHERE name LIKE '$q%'");

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$data[]=array('value'=>$row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: You could try changing your logic like that: `SELECT name 
  FROM tb_applicants
 WHERE substring(name, 1, $lngth) = $q;` where `$length=strlen($q);`

Comment: what is the ajax response? check network tab in developer tools and see if the problem is on php side or js side.

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut i think the problem is the query wont filter names with a space first like " red" and it will return null...how can i prevent it i got thousands of names here so hard to edit them.

Comment: That alone won't cause problems. Did you check the ajax output? Paste here pls.

Comment: If you need to select them too try `TRIM(name)` in your query

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut i uploaded the ajax output above please have a look.

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut the query read the first name in the table as null

Comment: can you put a `print_r($data)` instead of `echo json_encode($data);` and check the output again? so we could see what the array's first element is.

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut i updloaded please have a look

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut i knew the problem...my query wont filter names with a letter(Ñ) how can i make my query read it?

Comment: you should make sure that your array has only utf8 values since json_encode only accepts utf8. you can convert yours with iconv(). updated my answer with iconv()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47746/discussion-between-volkan-ulukut-and-user3311499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this before you run your query;

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

change the encoding and collation of your table and column to `utf8` - `utf8_general_ci`

change your php like this to avoid sending empty values:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
if(!empty($row['name']))
$data[]=array('value'=>$row['name']);
}
```

Comment: That will omit all those persons whose names are "null" :-) Here the thing is that during the iteration of mysql_fetch_array there are also numerical keys, none of which are 'name', hence the null.

Comment: wrong. mysql_fetch_array does not return first associative then array values, mysql_fetch_array returns the same amount of records with alternatives. that won't cause a null issue.

Comment: Oops, you're right, every $row is array('name'=>..., 0=>...) :(

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut my search function wont work if i use your code.

Comment: how come? did you try, or are you just talking? your search function is in mysql. this is php.

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut i used ur code but when i try to type a in my textbox none shows up.

Comment: then you are not entering your current charset right. look at your mysql table DDL and check which charset this field is using. if you are dealing with accented/multibyte data and do not know anything about encoding you gonna have a bad time.